# Make a nested array of subdirectories using RecursiveDirectoryIterator

Tags: php, recursion, foreach, spl

I have a following directory structure

```
test
  directory_in_test
    directory_in_directory_in_test
  directory2_in_test
    directory_in_directory2_in_test
  abc.php
index.php
```

I am trying to make a function that will give a multidimensional array of sub-directories. Required output something like :

```
[directories] => Array(
    [test] => Array(
        [directory_in_test] => Array(
            [directory_in_directory_in_test] => null
        )
        [directory2_in_test] => Array(
            [directory_in_directory2_in_test] => null
        )      
    )
)
```

I have tried to used `RecursiveIteratorIterator` with `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` but it give a one-level array of directories and files which is far from my requirement. Here is the code and result i have

**code**

```
<?php
    public function findDirectories($path = '', $like = '')
    {
        $path = (is_dir($path)) ? $path : getcwd();
        $directories = array();
        $iterator = new \RecursiveIteratorIterator(new \RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path));
        foreach ($iterator as $directory) {
            if($directory->isDir())
                $directories[] = $directory->getPathName();
        }

        return $directories;
    }
```

**Result on printing $directories**

```
Array
(
    [0] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\.
    [1] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\..
    [2] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory2_in_test\.
    [3] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory2_in_test\..
    [4] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory2_in_test\directory_in_directory2_in_test\.
    [5] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory2_in_test\directory_in_directory2_in_test\..
    [6] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory_in_test\.
    [7] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory_in_test\..
    [8] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory_in_test\direcotry_in_directory_in_test\.
    [9] => D:\xampp\htdocs\raheelwp\file-resolver\tests\directory_in_test\direcotry_in_directory_in_test\..
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator(".", RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($it);

$files = new RecursiveArrayIterator(array());
foreach ($it as $fi) {
    $it = $files;
    $dirs = explode('/', $fi->getPath());
    foreach ($dirs as $path) {
        if (isset($it[$path])) {
            $it = $it[$path];
        } else {
            $it[$path] = new RecursiveArrayIterator();
        }
    }

    $it[$fi->getFileName()] = $fi->getFileName();
}



$a = array();
createArray($a, $files);
print_r($a);

function createArray(&$a, $it) {
    foreach ($it as $k => $tmp) {
        if (is_string($tmp)) {
            $a[] = $tmp;
        } else {
            $a[$k] = array();
            createArray($a[$k], $tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

The code is fairly simple, and split in two parts even though it could easily be created in just one part. The first part will split the directories into separate `RecursiveArrayIterators`, so you keep the "iterator" capabilities to do all kind of other stuff with it. This is often useful when you are using the SPL iterators to begin with.

The second part, the `createArray` function basically uses an array reference to point to the "current" directory. Since it will be a multidimensional array, we do not have to worry about "where" in the array we actually are (it could be the 1st level, it might as well be the 100th level if your directory structure goes that deep). It just checks if the given element is a string, if so, it's a file, otherwise it's a directory so we recursively call the `createArray` again.

Might be easier solutions, but I reckon most of them uses a basic array-reference system nevertheless.